# How to compare colour values in Blender using Python?

Tags: python

I have scripted materials on some objects, now I want to make a simple if/else-comparison like this for only (1,1,1)-white material:

```
if (mat1.diffuse_color == (1,1,1)):
  # do something
else:
  # do something other
```

printing the color to the console gives me:

<Color (r=0.0000, g=0.0000, b=2.5000)>

I tried several ways but nothing worked, as you can see in my screenshot I must detect the white cubes by comparison their material-colour to white.

Thanks for any help on this!

Edit:
I read the [API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.types.Material.html?highlight=color#bpy.types.Material.diffuse_color)
[image: screenshot of Blender with my python script to the left]

Comment: So did any `print` actually return an array of `(1,1,1`)? Also note that the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.types.Material.html?highlight=diffuse_color#bpy.types.Material.diffuse_color) states that the values can be in the range [0,inf]. And floating point numbers have numerical inaccuracies, so comparison for equality is usually problematic. You could try something along the lines of `if(mat2.diffuse_color >= (0.9,0.9,0.9)):`

Comment: Thanks! That doesn't work ;-(
Actually I compare like this:
´if (mat2.diffuse_color[0] == 1.0 ):´
This works because the blue cubes don't have any red in their rgb-values.
But this ist not the best solution, there must be other ways for a in-array comparison.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention, that the blue cubes have randomed color. But only in the blue-rgb-value. 
When I printed out the color of a blue cube r and g were allways 0.0.

Comment: Suggest keeping your blue random color range to [0, 1].  Even if you are using randoms (`r`) ranging from 0 to 2.5 can set with with `max(r, 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically it's only possible to compare **equal data types**. By using python's built-in [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) method on [`Material.diffuse_color`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Material.html#bpy.types.Material.diffuse_color) the console yields it's an instance of the class [Color](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Color):

```
>>> type(bpy.data.materials.get("Red-Material").diffuse_color)
>>> <class 'Color'>
```

Probably the simplest way is to access its 'components' by class attribute `Material.diffuse_color.r` or index operator `Material.diffuse_color[0]` and compare the values:

```
# Check if the red component is 1.0 via equal operator
>>> bpy.data.materials.get("Red-Material").diffuse_color.r == 1 
>>> True 
>>> bpy.data.materials.get("Red-Material").diffuse_color[0] == 1 
>>> True
```

However, you can also compare two class instances:

```
>>> mat1_diff = bpy.data.materials.get("Red-Material-I").diffuse_color
>>> mat2_diff = bpy.data.materials.get("Red-Material-II").diffuse_color
>>> mat1_diff == mat2_diff
>>> True
```

Means that you can create a custom color *(class instance)* via [mathutils module](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Color) to compare with:

```
>>> import mathutils
>>> my_red_color = mathutils.Color((1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
>>> type (my_red_color)
>>> <class 'Color'>
>>> isinstance(my_red_color, Color)
>>> True
# Compare color instance with diffuse color
>>> bpy.data.materials.get("Red-Material").diffuse_color == my_red_color
>>> True
```

Answer (score 4):

Can treat [Color](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Color) values akin to [Vector](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector).
[image] 
The following example, subtracts two colors, normalized to [0, 1],  from each other.  The result is converted to a vector.  If the length of the resultant vector is less than some tolerance then the colors "match".

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Color

def color_match(col1, col2, tol=0.001):
    ''' 
    Return true if vector col1 is within tol of vector col2
    '''
    def vector(col):
        # sanitize range (-2, 3, 5) = (0, 1, 1)
        return Vector([max(0, min(1, c)) for c in col])

    d = vector(col1) - vector(col2)
    return d.length <= tol

# test code
white = Color((1, 1, 1))

# comparing instances 
Color((1, 1, 0.999999)) == white
# False

# same again using color_match no tol
color_match(Color((1, 1, 0.999999)), white, tol=0)
# False

# with default tol
color_match(Color((1, 1, 0.999)), white)
# True

color_match(Color((1, 1, 0.995)), white)
# False

# shorthand
color_match((1, 1, 1), white)
# True
```

Suggest always use some tolerance test (`fabs(x - y) < tol`)
when [Comparing Floating Point Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison)
.  An example in test code above is

```
Color((1, 1, 0.999999))
```

which is **NOT** equal to

```
Color((1, 1, 1))
```

when it may be more desirable that they are treated as equal (or close enough).